# Inserting data to MySQL database from XML feed

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Someone is helping me with this script to to insert XML data into MySQL, the XML data is from the audioscrobbler.com API, and I need to insert one row to the mysql database with the xml data **$song_album**, **$song_albumURL** and **$song_tag**, but even though I'm getting the data in the database, I adds the same song data like 12 times, and data is in different rows. Can I get HELP to correct this please?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "user";
$mysql_password = "pass";
$mysql_database = "database";
$myAPIKey = '****';

// Connect
$mysqli = new mysqli($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

$artist_raw = 'Metallica';
$title_raw = 'Whiskey In The Jar';
$artist = urlencode($artist_raw);
$title = urlencode($title_raw);

$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&api_key=$myAPIKey&artist=$artist&track=$title") 

   or die("Error: Cannot create object");


foreach($xml->track->children() as $track => $data){
$song_album = $data->title;
$song_tag = $data->tag->name[0];
$song_albumURL = $data->image[2];

$xml = NULL;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `music` (`song_title`, `song_artist`, `song_album`, `song_tag`, `song_albumURL`) values ('{$title_raw}', '{$artist_raw}', '{$song_album}', '{$song_tag}', '{$song_albumURL}')");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $song_album, $song_albumURL, $song_tag);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

}
?>
```

Here is the XML raw data:

```
<lfm status="ok">
<track>
<id>1003737</id>
<name>Whiskey in the Jar</name>
<mbid>664ae92a-f25a-4df4-a564-66ee87dff1c8</mbid>
<url>...</url>
<duration>303000</duration>
<streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
<listeners>433263</listeners>
<playcount>3389216</playcount>
<artist>
<name>Metallica</name>
<mbid>65f4f0c5-ef9e-490c-aee3-909e7ae6b2ab</mbid>
<url>http://www.last.fm/music/Metallica</url>
</artist>
<album position="9">
<artist>Metallica</artist>
<title>Garage, Inc.</title>
<mbid/>
<url>http://www.last.fm/music/Metallica/Garage,+Inc.</url>
<image size="small">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64s/54059755.png</image>
<image size="medium">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/54059755.png</image>
<image size="large">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/174s/54059755.png</image>
<image size="extralarge">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/300x300/54059755.png
</image>
</album>
<toptags>
<tag>
<name>metal</name>
<url>http://www.last.fm/tag/metal</url>
</tag>
<tag>
<name>heavy metal</name>
<url>http://www.last.fm/tag/heavy%20metal</url>
</tag>
<tag>
<name>hard rock</name>
<url>http://www.last.fm/tag/hard%20rock</url>
</tag>
<tag>
<name>rock</name>
<url>http://www.last.fm/tag/rock</url>
</tag>
<tag>
<name>cover</name>
<url>http://www.last.fm/tag/cover</url>
</tag>
</toptags>
<wiki>...</wiki>
</track>
</lfm>
```

Comment: Please share with us the debugging you have done so far (Does the code complete? Do all functions return values as expected? Any error message?)

Comment: I get no error messages, all values return, but it just keeps inserting the data over and over.

Comment: Are you sure? It looks like `$title_raw` is hard-coded, though. I wouldn't be surprised if `simplexml_load_file()` always loaded the same URL ;)

Comment: It is hard-coded for this test, but in the real script it changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `foreach` iterates over children of the `<track>` node, and inserts (incomplete) rows at each iteration (for each child node, that is).

That's not what you want. You want to insert one single row here. Remove your loop and do something like:

```
$song_album = $xml->track->album->title;
$song_tag = $xml->track->toptags->tag[0]->name;
dbQuery('INSERT INTO ...');
```